# Opening Another Instance of a Program?

Tags: unity, 12.04, command-line, unity-dash, gnome-terminal

I am testing out the use of Sakura instead of the Gnome Terminal. OS is Ubuntu 12.04 Precise. I often have multiple terminal windows open. How do you tell it to open a second window? Right clicking does not give you the option; and there is no menu along the top.

Is there a way to enable an "open another instance" option with right clicking? Or else, how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middle clicking the icon in the launcher should open a new instance.

Comment: what if i want to big front open software like when I click on nautilus icon, it opens new rather then 1 that is already opened.

Comment: Sorry DpN I do not know what you mean

Comment: @Jax-L Do you mean you want to open a new Tab? If the program supports it, go to File > New Tab.